# MSFconsole not starting from terminal after installing Metasploit Community

Tags: kali-linux, ruby-on-rails, metasploit

MSFconsole is not starting from terminal. It was just working yesterday. The only thing that has changed is that I have installed Metasploit Community.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    34: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/msfconsole:23:in `<main>'
    33: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/msfconsole:23:in `load'
    32: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/metasploit-framework-4.17.52/msfconsole:49:in `<top (required)>'
    31: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/metasploit-framework-4.17.52/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:81:in `start'
    30: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/metasploit-framework-4.17.52/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:63:in `require_environment!'
    29: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
    28: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    27: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/backports-3.13.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
    26: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/backports-3.13.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require'
    25: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/metasploit-framework-4.17.52/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    23: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    22: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    21: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    20: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    19: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    18: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    16: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    15: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    14: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    13: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    12: from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    11: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    10: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
     9: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
     8: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
     7: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
     6: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
     5: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
     4: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
     3: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
     2: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
     1: from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/wicked-0.5.0/app/controllers/wicked/wizard_controller.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)
```